# assign value from NSDictionary to NSManagedObject

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsdictionary, nsmanagedobject

My app requires to get data from a .Net WCF service when the device is connected to WiFi.If there's a new row added on the server,it should add it to its CoreData database. I am using a NSDictionary for comparing the local objects with the remote objects. The code is:

```
-(void)handleGetAllCategories:(id)value
{
    if([value isKindOfClass:[NSError class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"This is an error %@",value);
        return;
    }

    if([value isKindOfClass:[SoapFault class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"this is a soap fault %@",value);
        return;
    }

    NSMutableArray *result = (NSMutableArray*)value;
    NSMutableArray *remoteObj = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [result count]; i++)
    {
        EDVCategory *catObj = [[EDVCategory alloc]init];
        catObj = [result objectAtIndex:i];
        [remoteObj addObject:catObj];
    }

    NSArray *remoteIDs = [remoteObj valueForKey:@"categoryId"];

    NSFetchRequest  *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init]autorelease];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"categoryId IN %@", remoteIDs];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Categories" inManagedObjectContext:__managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[__managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil]];

    NSArray *existingIDs = [results valueForKey:@"categoryId"];
    NSDictionary *existingObjects = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:results forKeys:existingIDs];

    for (NSDictionary *remoteObjectDic in remoteObj) 
    {
        Categories *existingObject = [existingObjects objectForKey:[remoteObjectDic valueForKey:@"categoryId"]];

        if (existingObject) 
        {
            NSLog(@"object exists");
        } 
        else 
        {
            NSLog(@"create new local object");
//            Categories *newCategory;
//            newCategory = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Categories" inManagedObjectContext:__managedObjectContext];           
//            [newCategory setCategoryId:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[remoteObjectDic objectForKey:@"categoryId"]intValue]]];
//            [newCategory setCategoryName:[remoteObjectDic objectForKey:@"categoryName"]];  
//            [newCategory setDocCount:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[remoteObjectDic objectForKey:@"docCount"]intValue]]];
//            [newCategory setCategoryType:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[remoteObjectDic objectForKey:@"categoryType"]intValue]]];
//            [newCategory setSubCategoryId:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[remoteObjectDic objectForKey:@"subCategoryId"]intValue]]];
//            [__managedObjectContext insertObject:newCategory];
        }
    }
[my_table reloadData];
}
```

The problem is,I am not able to extract values from the remote object and assign it to the NSManagedObject.I have commented the code which (according to me) should save the values in new object to the managed object. Can someone please help me achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a save I did in a recent project. I have somethings in wrappers so fetching a managed object and saving look a little weird on my end.  Really the only major difference I see is the act of saving. Are you saving the new NSManagedObject elsewhere in the code?

```
dict = (NSDictionary*)data;
        @try {
            if (dict) {
                CaretakerInfo* info = [GenericDataService makeObjectWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([CaretakerInfo class])];
                [info setName:[dict valueForKey:@"name"]];
                [info setImageURL:[dict valueForKey:@"photo"]];
                [info setCaretakerID:[dict valueForKey:@"id"]];
                [GenericDataService save];
            }
            else {
                theError = [Error createErrorMessage:@"No Data" Code:-42];
            }
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            //return an error if an exception
            theError = [Error createErrorMessage:@"Exception Thrown While Parsing" Code:-42];
        }
```

If not it should looks something like this...

```
     NSError *error = nil;
     [context save:&error];
```

If you have anymore information about what's happening when you extract or assigning data that would be helpful (error/warning/log messages).

Comment: Now,if i were to delete an object from CoreData(bcoz it is deleted on the server) how would i do that?

Comment: [context deleteObject:object]; Dont forget to save after :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But how do I filter the existing objects from the remote objects and delete the ones which do not exist on the server?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what is being asked.  Are you asking "How do I clear my DB when I get new data in and store the new data?" "How do I update my DB to match the new data?"?  A bit more of a detailed example would be helpful :)

Comment: "How do I update my DB to match the new data?" is what I want to know.So,the data can be inserted,updated or deleted on the server.I want that to match with the data in CoreData.From your previous comment,I know how to "insert".But i am not sure how to compare the data in DB with that on the server and "delete" the outdated rows.So,the "comparison" is what I am looking for.

Comment: Awesome :) Sorry I had a busy day yesterday and wasn't on SO much

Comment: Thanks for your help. They pointed me in the right direction! :)